# The Construction of a Nested Sequence of Compactly Supported Open sets in $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ be open (potentially unbounded). The note that I am reading claim that the following construction could be done:

[image]

My question is, why exactly is this true? I think it is related to the general topological property that $\mathbf{R}^n$ is a normal space, but I am not entirely sure if this is the reason especially given that we need the union equal to the whole space $\Omega$. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: This is basic  and it is proved in Rudin's FA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for the comment! I haven't read Rudin's FA. Could you point me toward the section of book where the construction happens?

Comment: Yes it's an immediate consequence of $\Bbb R^n$ being second countable and locally compact Hausdorff.

Comment: Explicitly, take $\Omega_j=\{x: \|x\|\leq j, d(x, \Omega ^{c}) >\frac1  j \}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Could you elaborate a little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Find a countable cover of $\Omega$ by open sets with compact closures. Then take unions of appropriate finite subfamilies.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How's the distance between a point and a set defined when it is potentially empty, i.e. when $\Omega = \mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: The case $\Omega =\mathbb R^{n}$ is trivial. In all other cases the construction I gave works.

Comment: We'd also need $\Omega_j$ to be open, so the norm of $x$ should've been strictly less than j right?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So if $\{ U_i \}_{i = 1} ^\infty \subseteq P(\Omega)$ open covers $\Omega$, define $\Omega_j = \bigcup_{i = 1} ^j U_i$. Then $\Omega_j \subseteq \Omega_{j + 1}$. How do we guarantee that $\overline{\Omega_j} \subseteq \Omega_{j + 1}$ though?

Comment: Being careful... Go by recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\Bbb R^n$ is second countable (so hereditarily Lindelöf) and LCH, we can find a countable open cover $O_n, n \in \Bbb N$ of $\Omega$ so that for all $n$, $\overline{O_n} \subseteq \Omega$ is compact.

Define $\Omega_1=O_1$ and we can cover $\overline{O_1} = \overline{\Omega_1}$ by finitely many $O_n$, let that union be $\Omega_2$. Again $\overline{\Omega_2}$ is compact etc. We proceed by recursion.